# laravel 5.4 helper function asset

Tags: laravel-5.3

below code gives error FatalErrorException in b7233f5d5bc1ea1ea4b2b6e36abbbf198d2e611f.php 
syntax error, unexpected '{'

```
<a class="booking-item-review-person-avatar round" href="#">
<img src="asset('{{$trip->image}}')" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Afro" style="max-width: 120px;height:120px"/>
</a>
```

Comment: can you provide full code?

Comment: <a class="booking-item-review-person-avatar round" href="#">
                                            <img src="asset('{{$trip->image}}')" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Afro" style="max-width: 120px;height:120px"/>
                                        </a>

Comment: how can i use asset helper function i case of dynamic data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<img src="{{asset($trip->image)}}" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Afro" style="max-width: 120px;height:120px"/>
```